# Cannot release UIView in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc, retaincount

I've got this sample code I got from somewhere around the web.

My .h file looks like:

```
@interface PopupWindowString : CCNode <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIView *landscapeView;
    UITextField *username;
}
```

and my .m file in init method has:

```
landscapeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
CGAffineTransform tr = landscapeView.transform;
tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, (M_PI * -2.0));
landscapeView.transform = tr;
landscapeView.center = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].center;

username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 100, 160, 90)];
[username setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[username setDelegate:self];
[username setPlaceholder:@"New name"];
[username setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1.0]];
[landscapeView addSubview:username];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:landscapeView];
```

everything is cool and all but when I close the popup dealloc is not called.

It seems that the retainCount on landscapeView is still 1 after this code:

```
[username release];

[username removeFromSuperview];

[landscapeView release];

[landscapeView removeFromSuperview];
```

I have no clue about what to do with it... I don't have any other places I would use landscapeView, it's only in here.

I have tried subclassing UIView to try and figure out where from retain and release are called and here's the list:

Opening the popup:

1. Retain call from my PopupWindowString init method
2. Retain from [CALayer layoutSublayers]
3. Release from CALayerLayoutIfNeeded

Closing the popup: [I hit a CCMenuItemImage]

1. retain from [__NSArrayM addObject] in [UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
2. release from my code [the one I pasted previously]
3. release from my code [remove from subview]

As you can see one release is missing. I think, when closing the popup, this first retain is caused by me touching the view. However it is never released.

Anyone know how to soleve this one?

Thanks,
Krystian

Comment: The `retainCount` method can never return 0.  Don't call that method.  It is useless.

Comment: The whole thing was my mistake... I was trying to debug why the damn thing does not work and I was using a different way to remove the subviews [some kind of array over all of the subviews releasing them one by one]. During this I have removed the call to autorelease my Popup... then after all the changes I have made I simply forgot to put it back in... damn :( sorry for wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are balancing all of the retains implied or directly called with releases, then your job is done.

Are you sure the object is being leaked?  How have you determined that (note that `retainCount` is never the right answer)?

As written, that code does not appear to leak the `landscapeView`.  Note that if the code that releases it is not in your `dealloc`, you'll want to set `landscapeView` to nil to prevent a crash when you `[landscapeView release]` in `dealloc`.